# Faisait-on la liaison dans « l'un et l'autre » ?

Tags: prononciation, histoire, liaisons

J'ai un doute à propos de la prononciation de la locution *l'un et l'autre*.

Je n'ai jamais entendu un Français dire *l'un* ***n***'*et l'autre*, avec la liaison.

Tout de même, j'ai trouvé aujourd'hui dans le *[Manuel de la parole: Traité de prononciation](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Manuel_de_la_parole/11)* (1901) de J.-P. Garneau :

> [...] n se lie dans l’un et l’autre et l’un ou l’autre (l’un *n*’et
> l’autre, etc.).

C'est-à dire que l'on faisait cette liaison au début du XXème siècle ?

Comment: Je ne connais pas la réponse bien que le français soit ma première langue. J'ai l'impression qu'on peut faire ou ne pas faire cette liaison. Je crois que je ferais cette liaison, je ne perçois pas que ce serait particulièrement démodé. L'"arrêt" sur le "et" si on ne fait pas la liaison pourrait servir d'emphase, peut-être.

Answer (score 3):

C'est une liaison optionnelle.

L'une et l'autre de ces deux prononciations s'entendent couramment, la liaison étant plus « soignée », plus littéraire.

Par exemple : [YouTube Public Sénat](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sArYLERWmS0&t=250s)

La liaison est plus rare dans *l'un ou l'autre*.

Comment: C'est un cas intéressant étant donné qu'il semble être gouverné par deux règles contradictoires : ne jamais faire la liaison avec *et*, et la faire toujours dans une expression lexicalisée (comme l'aurait Wikipédia).

Comment: @LukeSawczak Oui, c'est une bonne remarque. On fait plus souvent la liaison quand  *l'un et l'autre* est dit d'un trait, correspond à une seule entité fusionnée alors que la liaison a tendance à disparaitre s'il y a séparation, séquencement.